# Running mvn install with running tomcat plugin parallel

Tags: java, maven, configuration, embedded-tomcat-7

In the project there are unit tests and frontend html tests that need running webserver.
In order to `mvn install` pass well, I need both kind of these tests pass well.
I use embedded tomcat server, that is started via tomcat plugin for maven:

```
mvn tomcat7:run
```

So, I start tomcat (it's needed for my frontend html tests),
then try to start: `mvn install` in the command line, but get the following error:

```
D:\PROJECTS\SpringMvcExample>mvn install
ERROR: transport error 202: bind failed: Address already in use
ERROR: JDWP Transport dt_socket failed to initialize, TRANSPORT_INIT(510)
JDWP exit error AGENT_ERROR_TRANSPORT_INIT(197): No transports initialized [../../../src/share/back/debugInit.c:741]
FATAL ERROR in native method: JDWP No transports initialized, jvmtiError=AGENT_ERROR_TRANSPORT_INIT(197)
```

at the same time, when tomcat is started, I can run `mvn install` via Intellij Idea plugin for maven, and it works fine without any error.

My question how how to configure in order to start maven in the command line?

It's maven multimodule project, here is pom.xml of the web module:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
         xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>com.savdev</groupId>
    <artifactId>SpringMvcExample</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
<artifactId>web</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<name>SpringMvcExample Webapp</name>

<properties>
    <spring.version>3.2.4.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <selenium.version>2.37.1</selenium.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <!--modules dependency start-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.savdev</groupId>
        <artifactId>model</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.savdev</groupId>
        <artifactId>service</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <!--modules dependency end-->

    <!--web dependency start-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
        <version>7.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!--web dependency end-->

    <!--tests dependency-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.11</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!--<dependency>-->
        <!--<groupId>org.mockito</groupId>-->
        <!--<artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>-->
        <!--<version>1.9.5</version>-->
        <!--<scope>test</scope>-->
    <!--</dependency>-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sourceforge.jwebunit</groupId>
        <artifactId>jwebunit-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!--<dependency>-->
        <!--<groupId>net.sourceforge.jwebunit</groupId>-->
        <!--<artifactId>jwebunit-htmlunit-plugin</artifactId>-->
        <!--<version>3.1</version>-->
    <!--</dependency>-->
    <!--<dependency>-->
        <!--<groupId>net.sourceforge.htmlunit</groupId>-->
        <!--<artifactId>htmlunit</artifactId>-->
        <!--<version>2.13</version>-->
    <!--</dependency>-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>${selenium.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-firefox-driver</artifactId>
        <version>${selenium.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-chrome-driver</artifactId>
        <version>${selenium.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-htmlunit-driver</artifactId>
        <version>${selenium.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <finalName>SpringMvcExample</finalName>
    <!--to run into debug mode set:-->
    <!--export MAVEN_OPTS=-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=8000,server=y,suspend=n-->
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <path>/SpringMvcExample</path>
                <url>http://localhost:8080/manager/text</url>
                <server>tomcat7</server>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: please include your `pom.xml`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to bind tomcat `run`/`shutdown` to suitable `<execution>` phases:

```
<phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
<goals>
  <goal>run</goal>
</goals>
```

and

```
<phase>post-integration-test</phase>
<goals>
  <goal>shutdown</goal>
</goals>
```

Having it configured like this you **shouldn't start tomcat by hand** (i.e. by `mvn tomcat7:run`). It should run automatically before tests and shutdown after them.